# $\lim_{x\to 0} \big(\lim_{y\to0} f(x,y)\big)$ doesn't exist.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Here is a problem in calculus:

> Let $$ f(x,y)=  \begin{cases}     y+x\sin\bigg(\frac{1}{y}\bigg),&  y\neq0\\\\0,& y=0 \end{cases}$$
>    show that :
>
> 1. $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} f(x,y)$ and $\lim_{y\to 0} \big(\lim_{x\to0} f(x,y)\big)$ exist.
> 2. $\lim_{x\to 0} \big(\lim_{y\to0} f(x,y)\big)$ doesn't exist.

It is an elementary question here and I could solve the first part only. Taking different paths couldn't also help me. May I ask to help me about the second part? Give me the right path reaching the origin. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\lim_{y\to 0}f(x,y)$ doesn't exist is due to the fact that $\lim_{y\to 0}\sin\frac 1y$ doesn't exist. To see that, work with the sequences $y_n:=\frac 1{2\pi n}$ and $z_n:=\left(2\pi n+\frac{\pi}2\right)^{—1}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am searching for this magic seq. Thanks Davide. :)

Answer (score 2):

$\lim \limits_{x\to 0} \left(\lim \limits_{y\to 0} f(x,y)\right)$ does not exist, because for $x\ne 0$ doesn't exist $\lim \limits_{y\to 0} \sin{\frac{1}{y}}$